# calling a function onerror of img src

Tags: angular, onerror

This is my code in angular 2:

```
test.component.html:
<img src="./assets/sample.jpeg" onError="setValue()">
{{imageMenu}}

test.component.ts:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
imageMenu:boolean = true;
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {

  }
  setValue():void{
    alert("hi");
    this.imageMenu = !this.imageMenu;
  } 
}
```

My question is when the image source is empty, even then the Boolean value is true. `setValue()` is not getting called on error. Pls guys help me to resolve this. I am new to angular.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you are using HTML DOM events in Angular remove the `on` prefix from the event and use it. ex

`onclick` ---> `(click)`

use `(error)` instead of onError

```
<img src="assets/sample.jpeg" (error)="setValue()">
```